# How to reinstall Unity apps on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: reinstalling

I have been searching around the web for days for this.
I installed xfce a few days ago. Now i am having wifi problem, so and i would like to go back to unity.

I first did this:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop gksu leafpad synaptic
```

followed by this command;

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-termina* gnome-pane* gnome-applet* gnome-bluetooth gnome-desktop* gnome-sessio* gnome-user* gnome-shell-common compiz compiz* unity unity* hud zeitgeist zeitgeist* python-zeitgeist libzeitgeist* activity-log-manager-common gnome-control-center gnome-screenshot overlay-scrollba* &&
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-community-wallpapers &&
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop should give you a default Ubuntu install, but where did you get those instructions? It seems to me your wifi issues should be the actual question, this seems to be an xyz problem.

Comment: I think xfce did something to my kernel which is why i need to completely remove it without traces and get back to unity. i followed the instructions from this website. https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative

Comment: tried sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop, but still having wifi issue. Do you know how to remove xfce grub and welcome screen files? Still have xfce welcome screen

Comment: Like I said this seems to be an xyz problem, I recommend you to make a new question and focus on your first actual issue. There's also Ubuntu forums.